# How to build rviz_rendering?

Tags: ros2, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to compile rviz_rendering with the command `colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select rviz_rendering` I get following stacktrace:

```
--- stderr: rviz_rendering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lassimp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rviz_rendering.dir/build.make:515: librviz_rendering.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:344: CMakeFiles/rviz_rendering.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and a ros_rolling master source checkout of ros2.
I have both assimp-utils and assimp-testmodels installed. This is my output for `ls -la | grep assimp`

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        18 Feb 13  2020 libassimp.so.5 -> libassimp.so.5.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  12846808 Feb 13  2020 libassimp.so.5.0.0
```

How can I get rviz_rendering to build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384124/how-to-build-rviz_rendering?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Deleting the rviz_rendering folder in the build folder and rebuilding the package fixed this error

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0